# Charts lineChartDataset rounded values

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swift3, ios-charts

I'm trying out a few things with the iOS Charts library with Swift 3.0.
I have a question about formatting of the lineChartDataset values (displayed above each value point). Right now these values are 'double' and are displayed as 2.0 and 3.0 instead of just 2 and 3 etc. Is it possible to round these values? I tried with numberFormatter but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Until I understand you are using Daniel's Chart https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts library in that case you have to use xAxis label formatting approach. Can you share your code related to numberFormatter?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to do something with lineChartDataset.valueFormatter = NumberFormatter() but I get an error: Cannot assign value of type 'NumberFormatter' to type 'IValueFormatter?'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ios-charts have been upgraded to protocol base approach for rendering the various kind of labels like xAxis, yAxis etc. So you have to implement protocol `IValueFormatter` in order to achieve the required results. I have created the class for the same, so directly use this as below & you would be able to achieve desired results.

Create a class named as `DigitValueFormatter` & assign that to `LineChartData` object as `lineChartData.setValueFormatter(DigitValueFormatter())`

```
import Foundation
import Charts

class DigitValueFormatter : NSObject, IValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double,
                        entry: ChartDataEntry,
                        dataSetIndex: Int,
                        viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        let valueWithoutDecimalPart = String(format: "%.0f", value)
        return "\(valueWithoutDecimalPart)"
    }
}
```